# What causes the error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/0x8007000d and how to fix it?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bunch of wsl ubuntu distributions installed on my Windows 11 box and they all used to work.  Now, when I attempt to boot (run them from wsl) any of them, they all fail with "The data is invalid" and the above error code.  The same thing happens if I attempt to install new copies of Ubuntu.

e.g.

```
wsl -d u20.04 -u cfclark
The data is invalid.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVM/0x8007000d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x8007000d` is commonly caused by an expired Windows Insider build preventing WSL and Ubuntu from launching.  If you are running Windows Insider, make sure that you are completely updated.  If your build is expired, you may need to try setting your system date back to a time when it isn't expired, then update.  If all else fails, and your Windows build is very out-of-date, you may need to reinstall from ISO.

If you do need to reinstall, you may want to back up the `ext4.vhdx` files for any WSL2 distributions.  You can find them by running the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ |
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPATH) | Select-Object DistributionName,BasePath
}
```

If you have any WSL1 distributions, then things may be more challenging.

If you are not on an Insider build or are fully updated, then let me know, and we can investigate further.

Reference:

- [Can't open wsl possibly after update "the data is invalid"](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8826)
- [WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007000d](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6592)
- [Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/0x8007000d in windows 11](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9065)
- and others

Comment: Thanks for I finally also found this thread which addresses the issue you point out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804842/ubuntu-on-wsl-is-inaccessible-and-prompts-data-invalid

Comment: Of course, part of the problem is that I am currently not able to update my windows insider build (getting on that was a mistake on my part, but separate issue), but currently w11 2022 h2 refuses to boot on my system and thus keeps rolling back to this outdated insiders build.  :-(

Comment: BTW, once you get the version working, you don't need to fix the date each time.  Moreover, setting the date back (temporarily) allowed me to install the preview version (23.10) which was my actual goal.  And, I can now run it without fiddling with the dates.